# Is there a service where you can send and receive WhatsApp message into web application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, whatsapp

We are developing a web application where we communicate with the customer for product price details. Currently, we are using Email and Messages to communicate with our Customers. But we can only receive messages from Email hence we were searching for alternatives like WhatsApp.

Is there a way we can send messages to WhatsApp from Web Application and receive replays which would be sent from WhatsApp?

We are using Spring and Java for Development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime ago I needed something similar and couldn't find anything for Java. On the other hand, there is [yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup), which is a library for Python which works really well.

After a lot of searching around without success, I ended up writing everything related to Whatsapp in Python and making it comunicate with my Java app.

Just keep in mind when doing anything related to Whatsapp, since there is no oficial api, it usually requires more maintenance and you have no garantee that what you built won't simply stop working on the next day due to an update on Whatsapp side that changed something the unoficial client isn't expecting.